# Issue about serving html and drawing in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, d3.js

I have encountered a problem when node.js is serving a html file which contains svg drawing.

The index.html contains a chart which is identical to the line chart at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245

The problem is whenever I am serving the index.html through express server, I get a blank page.(Blank page at 127.0.0.1:80)  However, the line chart will appear if I open the index.html file locally.  (Page works fine at file:///F:/d3/index.html)

main.js source code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.get('/', function(req, res){                  
    var index = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html', "utf8");
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    res.write(index);
    res.end();
});

server.listen(80);
```

The chart is drawn by d3.

Comment: Are you sure your d3 library is being loaded by your browser?

Comment: Yes. I am sure. I double clicked F:\d3\index.html and chart appeared. But the browser displayed nothing when visiting through nodejs web server (127.0.0.1 or localhost)

Comment: You clearly don't understand my comment. How are you sure d3.js is being loaded when you run through node?

Comment: I did add <script src="node_modules/d3/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script> to the <head>

Comment: When you navigated to `127.0.0.1:80`, got a blank page, and then opened your javascript console to look for errors; what were the errors?

Comment: I find the problem but I don't know how to solve it.  Filefox console gave me this :                                                                                                 GET http://127.0.0.1/node_modules/d3/d3.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 4ms]
ReferenceError: d3 is not defined.                                                        The problem is I know the d3.js do exist

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. The server feature of node.js is very basic. Unlike IIS or Apache, node doesn't have the concept of what a web server is. Each file request needs to be manually handled.

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var fs = require('fs');

//load d3 for index.html
app.get('/d3/d3.js', function(req, res){
    var d3 = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/d3/d3.js', "utf8"); 
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/javascript"});
    res.write(d3);
    res.end();
});

//load chart data for d3
app.get('/data.tsv', function(req, res){
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/data.tsv', 'utf8', function(err, data){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("data req received.")
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        }
    });
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

server.listen(80);
```

D3 chart drawing was successfully displayed.